# To retire a DC while still mainitaing DHCP? Does DNS have a factor in this?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, controller

Org has a 2008 R2 Server that is a DC and File Server. Idea is to retire the DC, and have accounts routed through other DCs. Also, it has been noted, that DHCP must remain up on this server. To my knowledge, it seems that DNS zones tie into DHCP. What considerations should I be noting?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you update your DHCP Scope and/or DHCP Server options with the correct/appropriate DNS servers.
2. Make sure that you update your DHCP Scope and/or DHCP Server options with the correct/appropriate DNS domain name (it's a given that you already have this, but verify it).
3. Make sure that you have a DNS zone matching the DNS domain name in your DHCP Scope and/or Server Options (it's a given that you already have this, but verify it).